# How to get associated polymorphic objects in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

In my Post model, I have

```
has_many :followers
```

In my Follower model, I have

```
belongs_to :model
belongs_to :owner,polymorphic: true
```

In my User and Admin devise models, I have

```
has_many :followers,as: :owner
```

**Requirement:**  I want to have something like `Post.owners`  and it should return me a list of all users and/or admins that are following this post.

Comment: is admin associated with user or not?

Comment: No, Admin model is a separate devise model and not associated with User model.

Comment: have you defined `owner_type (string) & owner_id` in followers table?

Comment: Yes I have these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that AR doesn't provide a way to load polymorphic associations in just one query. But you can use:

```
post = Post.find(1)
post_followers = post.followers.includes(:owner)
post_owners = post_followers.map(&:owner)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you're looking for is polymorphic has many through. You can add these lines in your model of User and Admin.

```
has_many :followers
has_many :posts, through: :followers, source: :owner, source_type: 'Owner'
```

Comment: I want to have something from Post to User/Admin, in opposite direction.

Comment: Yeah this will create a reverse association from post using followers table as a joining table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, as: :owner
end

class Follower < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, as: :owner
end
```

From an instance of your User you can then retrieve their posts with @user.posts
The same goes for your Follower, @follower.posts

If you want to get to the parent of your post instance, you can do so via @post.owner.  To make this work, however, we need to set up the schema correctly by  declaring both a foreign key column and a type column in the model that declares the polymorphic interface using the references form:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      # your attribs here
      t.references :owner, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have this in my schema. This will return me all of the posts a User has wrote, But I want all of the followers of a specific Post. The user who creates any Post is added as a follower of that Post, and then whenever any other User or Admin adds any Comment on this Post, they are also added as Follower of this Post. So I should be able to send Notifications to all of the Followers of any Post.

Comment: Hm. Strange. Just to be clear: You are saying that with an instance of a post: `post = Post.last`, you cannot do `post.owners` to get all the Users/Followers for that post?

Comment: yes, exactly, right now I cannot do this but I want to do this.